# fetch, reset the Spinner value and call onCreate method explicitly

Tags: android, spinner

Here I have 2 spinner in this code. When button1 is clicks, the following process is to do. The process is about fetch the spinner values and those values is must store in total variable and selected spinner values must be reset to original position. This action should perform how many times button is clicked.

Spinner cre1, cre2;

float total;

String credit1, credit2;

ArrayAdapter spin1;

ArrayAdapter spin2;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

    creditd = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spin1);
    graded = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spin2);

    cre1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cre1);
    spin1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    cre1.setAdapter(creditd);
    cre1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            credit1 = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    cre2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cre2);
    spin2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    gra1.setAdapter(graded);
    gra1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            credit2 = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });


    total += convf(credit1) + convf(credit2);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            onCreate(new Bundle());
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Result.class));
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using Spinners setSelection method to reset selected postion like whenever you want:

```
spin1.setSelection(position); 
spin2.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: But I understand the concept of reset. Here I need to know that how to recall all the spinner in onCreate explicitly. Because I want to loop the process for certain times to get the value of spinners when the button is clicks.